# Monitor network connection with systemd

Tags: systemd, networkmanager

I have a Linux server that needs to connect to a VPN over a somewhat unreliable connection. At times, the connection will drop, and and the server loses all access until Network Manager is restarted. The connection will *appear* to be up, but pinging any non-local address will fail. (`systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` is almost always the easiest and correct fix).

The OpenVPN client supports `--ping-restart`, but I can't find any equivalent functionality for NetworkManager, or a way to handle this in systemd.

I can think of a way to hack this together using a bash script and a cron job or systemd timer (ie, ping a known IP address periodically and restart networkmanager.service if it fails). But that seems somewhat brittle, and I imagine there must be a cleaner way to monitor the network connection under systemd.

Comment: Restarting NetworkManager service is almost never the right thing to do. Unless you workaround a bug in NM, but then it would be better to report/fix the bug. You probably should just reactivate the connection with `nmcli connection up "$NAME"`.

Comment: The connection appears to be up, but it cannot connect to the WAN. So the question remains: how do I monitor for the loss of the WAN connection?

Comment: That sounds like a bug, maybe not of NetworkManager but the lower layers. Preferably, you'd fix the bug. But sure, you may workaround by having a service that periodically tries to ping the internet and fix the connection by whatever means appropriate. You could write a script and run it as system (systemd) service.

Comment: Can you analyse /var/log/messages anything useful can be logged there